# ANTLR 3 - how do I make unique tokens with NOT across special chars

Tags: utf-8, antlr, special-characters

I have a short question:

```
// Lexer 
LOOP_NAME   :   (LETTER|DIGIT)+;

OTHERCHARS  :   ~('>' | '}')+;

LETTER      :   ('A'..'Z')|('a'..'z');

DIGIT       :   ('0'..'9');

A_ELEMENT
    :       (LETTER|'_')*(LETTER|DIGIT|'_'|'.');

// Parser-Konfiguration
WS          : ( ' '     
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
            | '\n'
            ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
            ;
```

My problem is that this is impossible due to:

> As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input [14:55:32]
>   error(208): ltxt2.g:61:1: The following token definitions can never be
>   matched because prior tokens match the same input:
>   LETTER,DIGIT,A_ELEMENT,WS

My issue is that I also need to catch UTF8 with OTHERCHARS... and I cannot put all special UTF8 chars into a Lexer rule since I cannot range like ("!".."?").

So I need the NOT (~). The OTHERCHARS here can be everything but ">" or "}". These two close a literal context and are forbidden within.

It doesn't seem such cases are referenced very well, so I'd be happy if someone knew a workaround. The NOT operator here creates the ambivalence I need to solve.

Thanks in advance.

Best,
wishi

Comment: OTHERCHATS would be "!" but also "ü" or UTF8. I don't know. I have to be able to ignore free text and find "<% Special >". Then Special is going to be replaced (stuff from DB). The issue is that ANTLR has no character classes and I cannot range special chars. ">" and "}" close contexts (loops and the clutter around the "Special".

Comment: also I edited my question to structure it in a clear way. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `OTHERCHARS` to the very end of the lexer and define it like this:

```
OTHERCHARS : . ;
```

In the Java target, this will match a single UTF-16 code point which is not matched by a previous rule. I typically name the rule `ANY_CHAR` and treat it as a fall-back. By using `.` instead of `.+`, the lexer will only use this rule if no other rule matches.

1. If another rule matches more than one character, that rule will have priority over `ANY_CHAR` due to matching a larger number of characters from the input.
2. If another rule matches exactly one character, that rule will have priority over `ANY_CHAR` due to appearing earlier in the grammar.

Edit: To exclude `}` and `>` from the `ANY_CHAR` rule, you'll want to create rules for them so they are covered under point 2.

```
RBRACE   : '}' ;
GT       : '>' ;
ANY_CHAR : . ;
```

Comment: I would need to exclude "}" and ">". The ~ (NOT) seems to bind differently

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm one step further... but not exactly sure... jet. free_text : (LETTER | DIGIT | OTHERCHARS)* would be fore free text... but I don't think that's possible, is it? Since I have to exclude } or > from free text.